# What is the best way to neglect undefined variables in GTM , Where the data is not availble .

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have implemented GTM and GA with event based tracking. Alongside events tracking I have implemented **custom dimensions and Custom Variables**. In all the pages All defined Custom metrics and dimensions are populated according to needs , which is giving empty data in some cases.

for Ex. When user Registers on our page their Registration will be added to data layer object for custom dimensions but this info is not available on every part of the website..

Kindly help and suggest what to do . Do  I need to create several tags for specific  conditions or track the issues with develops where they can give custom info when the data is not available .

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in an "undefined" value to a custom dimension or metric then Google Analytics will just treat it as if the dimension or metric was not set at all. I.e. you will not have "undefined" in your reports, but no value at all. So you could just ignore the issue.

As an alternative you could set a default value that is used when no other value is available (i.e. for filtering).